# Add Angular 4 to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Application (MVC)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

Now that ASP.NET Core 2 is released, I have started to build a Web Application (MVC) using ASP.NET CORE in Visual Studio 2017. However when trying to add Angular 4 (or 2) to the existing project I find many outdated tutorials on the net. 
I would like some guidance on how and which procedure to chose (Angular CLI, WebPack, Manually etc.)

I'm aware there is a SPA (Angular) template inside visual studio 2017, however I've preferred to create a MVC web app first.

Comment: Have you read this article?  “How to build an Angular Application with ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2017, visualized” https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa

Comment: yes, that article is quite verbose, I was not able to get it working following that article

Comment: I followed the same article and had no problem. Try searching more maybe

Comment: the articles is not suited for asp.net core 2

Comment: The articles says "These three templates create actually the same sample application" which is not correct

Comment: @Ovis, use this https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices if you create new app yo generator creates for you project file and you able to work with VS2017

Comment: The "Installation into existing projects" does not deal with angular setup