# add Angular SPA into existing .net Core MVC Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, .net-core, single-page-application

First I have visited many stackover flow question & answers regarding similar questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800595/add-angular-4-to-asp-net-core-2-0-web-application-mvc) article. **So I hope no Genius will mark this as broad or No Direct Question, and let someone answer.**

Question: I have a running asp.net core MVC web application, and one part inside this existing application I want to convert into a SPA using Angular (Not angularJS). I have come across many articles on how to build an Angular Application with ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio, but nor any approach on how in include angular app I made into a MVC page.

Is it possible to do & if so, Guidline on how to do, Article to follow may highly appreciated.

Comment: I made very simple skeleton project to build application using .Net core & Angular 4. Here is my repo https://github.com/ngohungphuc/Angular4-ASP.NetCore If you have any question please let me know